# Problems with LDAP and Drupal

Tags: drupal

**EDIT**
(But please read it all if you really wanna help :) )
Since I'm able to view all the profiles with the correct LDAP data (it's fetched when asked for, but never stored), an possible, albeit hackish solution, would be to display all the profiles as a table. Does anyone have an idea how that might be done ? Google hasn't help, understandably since most people never need to use such a feature.
**EDIT**

I've successfully used the LDAP Integration module to use LDAP authentication with Drupal. Now I'm trying to create an address book with information from LDAP. I've tried the following solution:

Changed the ldap_data.module, the part that states which fields can be mapped between ldap and drupal (e.g. mail => mail). This fails when I try to add more mappings. I believe this maps to the "users" table in drupal, but when I try to add a field to that table and map a LDAP attribute to it, nothing goes into the database. My plan was to then use Table Wizard with views to create the address book. Using Table Wizard and Views I was able to extract everything I wanted from the users table, but the problem of entering data into the table is still not solved.

If you have any ideas, any at all, I'd really appreciate it. I'm a beginner in drupal and LDAP altogether btw. I've already tried to google this to death over the last few days but nothing has helped me solve this problem.

The answer below helped me understand why this didn't work, but the problem is still unsolved.

Comment: Please do not cross post questions: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5303/problems-with-ldap-and-drupal

Answer (score 2):

The LDAP Data module is not intended to work with fields arbitrarily added to the users table. Instead, it works in conjunction with the [core Profiles module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/profile) and can [map to its fields](http://drupal.org/node/118123).

Comment: All right, that makes sense, since I was able to add data to the field "language"...but using fields for another purpose than intended is not a great idea. Do you have any ideas for alternative ways to do this, such as making LDAP info go into a new table in the database or do you know of modules that take care of this ?

Comment: Can't you use the Profiles module to add the fields you need to map to, to the users profile's?

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, the thing is that I'm able to get all this info to the users profiles, that was the easy part. Displaying the info in a view is the hard part since it's not stored in the database, but rather fetched from LDAP. I'll try to mess around with the profile module a bit though. Thanks alot for your help and I'll post this on the Drupal Answers site.